# How to setup WASM IdentityServer with user/pass authentication AND device authentication with client/secret from a console application

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I have a typical Blazor WASM project, Server, Client and Shared. Authentication with IdentityServer is setup and working correctly. I'm receiving the JWT when I login with a user and I can get the discovery document.

Aside from normal users, I want to connect devices. These devices are not users so it seems wrong to create a user for each device. If I create a user then I can login and get the token. But I added InMemoryClients, so I was under the assumption that I could login as a client with id/secret using the device authentication endpoint of the discovery document.

I added a console application that is running on the device. But authentication fails returning "invalid_client".

In the server app I defined a Client and ApiScope:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
    new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("api", "My API")
        };

public static IEnumerable<IdentityServer4.Models.Client> Clients =>
    new List<IdentityServer4.Models.Client>
    {
        new IdentityServer4.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "device",

            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret")
            },

            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api" }
        }
    };
```

They are added with the AddInMemory functions in the Startup.Configure method:

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
            });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44316";
                options.Audience = "api";
            }) 
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

In the console app I send a DeviceAuthenticationRequest:

```
static IDiscoveryCache _cache = new DiscoveryCache("https://localhost:44316");

var disco = await _cache.GetAsync();
if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

var client = new HttpClient();
response = await client.RequestDeviceAuthorizationAsync(new DeviceAuthorizationRequest
{
    //Address = disco.TokenEndPoint, // same result
    Address = disco.DeviceAuthorizationEndpoint,
    ClientId = "device",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    Scope = "api"
});
```

The response in the client contains an error, "invalid_client". And the server complains also:

```
IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator: Error: No client with id 'client' found. aborting
```

I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Obviously the typo was a problem. But I managed to fix it by changing the AllowedGrantTypes to:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantTypes.ClientCredentials, GrantTypes.DeviceFlow };
```

However! I had to removed api authorization, need to figure out how to add it back:

```
.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
});
```

And instead of specifying options for and adding JwtBearer:

```
//services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
//    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
//    {
//        options.Authority = "https://localhost:44316";
//        options.Audience = "api";
//    }) 
//    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

I just have this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have just a small typo. In the Startup.cs the `ClientId = "device"`. In your client, you set `ClientId = "client"`.

In general, you are right. You don't need to create a client for each user and their potential devices. The definition of one client for all possible users and devices is enough. You could even debate if a client's password is necessary and increase security. [In the official docs, the secret is optional.](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/device_authorization.html)

In a simplified view: the "client part" of this authentication flow is mainly used to generate the user code. In a second (asynchronous) step, a user with different device logins to authenticate the device by entering the previously generated code.

For more details of a look at [this](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/02/08/try-device-flow-with-identityserver4/) post.

Comment: Thanks for the typo, but I get the same result. However, it's not a device of a user, it's just a device. I don't want to have a user involved. I have separate users, but they don't own the device. The device stands on its own.

Comment: Despite the client authentication error, let's focus on what you want to accomplish within the authentication flow.

The device flow always needs a user. The device will make calls to your API on behalf of the user. If I remember correctly, the Amazon Prime Video App on the Xbox has this behavior. The IdentityServer4 Quickstart's DeviceController use the Authorize attribute, 

If you want to call your API without a user, that means you have a "server-to-server" flow. In this case, use the client and secret.

Comment: To host the API and IdentityServer int the same project
have a look at this example https://github.com/brockallen/IdentityServerAndApi

Comment: thanks @just-the-benno, that helped clear my confusion. I was under the assumption that I could do it without user. Changed to clientcredentials and it works now, I'm getting the token. 
But then I want to use the token to setup a SignalR connection using the AccessTokenProvider in the WithUrl method and that tells me it's not authorized. I need to figure out how to [Authorize] SignalR comm with the token.

Comment: Indeed  SignalR and jwt authentication are special. Unlike normal HTTP calls, SignalR, and the WebSocket protocol, don't use the concept of headers. The workaround is to send the token as a query parameter. This needs to be done by the client. On the server-side, to have the same comfort level, we intercept the authentication process and set the token from the query as "the" access token. This document[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz] explains how it's done. 
Check if your client is sending the token as a query and if the server receives it.

Comment: I have been reading that document for a week. I get the token now, I also pass it as a query string to the HubConnectionBuilder, but as soon as I use [Authorize(Policy = "ApiScope")] or just [Authorize] on the Hub I get a 401.              services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
                {
                    //policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api");
                });
            });

Comment: Have you verified that the token is sent as a query parameter? Inspect the communication via the network tab in the developer console of your browser.

Set a  breakpoint into the ``` OnMessageReceived  ``` method to see what happen. Is ```  context.Token ``` not set? 

If the server method is not invoked, that is an indication that authorization is not configured properly. If it is invoked and works correctly, and you still get a 401. Try a "normal" API call first to see if the authentication works in general and work your way from there.

Comment: After getting the token in the client successfully and trying to connect to the hub context.Token is set properly in OnMessageReceived. That only happens when the path is myhub/negotiate. If stepping further, just after the OnMessageReceived ends, the 401 is sent and the process ends.
I'm working with a console app and HttpClient. Authentication works, I have a Blazor wasm client that also receives/sends and authenticates SignalR communication. However, not with client secret credentials but with user password and I had to add the AddApiAuthorization code to add support for roles.

Comment: Could you send me a repo to play around with?

Comment: I would if I could, the project is a little too complex to pass around and it's proprietary. I'm setting it up from scratch now with the .net 5 templates to see if I encounter the same problems. Maybe I missed something during the migration from 3.1 to 5.0 ... or the custumizations I made create problems. I hope to figure it out :/

Comment: maybe you could checkout my other question? I've narrowed it down. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955291/how-to-combine-multiple-authentication-schemes-for-different-types-of-clients-u

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I've read through it and have some ideas that I want to test first. Today is a bit busy, but I try to answer later.  :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, no worries. I got it working for user/password and clientcredentials. Now working to add SignalR. I had to add a Client in the IClientStore for the Blazor client to work. Normally it's added by AddIdentityJwt but I guess it gets overwritten or something, not sure.